# Spring is bypassing the method and showing the cache content when adding parameters in the redirect URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching, proxy

I have a problem with the next code. Hope you can help me:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/method1")
    public String method1(String userName, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
       request.getSession().setAttribute("userName" userName);
       String redirect = "redirect:/method2";
        redirect = redirect + "?success";
        return redirect;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/method2")
    public String method2(HttpServletRequest request
            ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "success", required = false) String success) {
           String userName=request.getSession().getAttribute("userName");
           System.out.println("userName " + userName); //This doesn't show the second time
           return "user";
    }
```

The first time I call `method1` with `Username Peter`, `method2` is invoked and the URL `/method2?success` shows the data of the user `Peter`.

Then, if I call again `method1` with `Username Natalie`, the URL `/method2?success` with `Peter`'s data is shown. That is, the second time `method2` is not being invoked but the cache content is shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: please update the question with details on how are you testing this ( example , URL used to hit the server , postman payload etc )